# How to collect only part of Geo IP data(like 'country' and 'continent' )

Tags: keen-io

I'm using Keen IO with the Geo IP Enrichment add-on. It works fine but I would only like to collect the 'country' and 'continent' data rather than all of it. However I cannot find how to do it. Does anyone know how this can be done? (The reason I want to do this is a "better safe than sorry" approach to GDPR)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, with Keen IO's [Data Enrichment add-ons](https://keen.io/docs/streams/data-enrichment-overview/) it is all or nothing.

One suggestion: You use a library to get the IP to Geo data on the client side, then only add the information you want to keep to the event that you are sending to Keen IO.